# Why do these complements of closed sets induced by annihilators form an open cover of the spectrum?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For an important characterization of morphisms to projective spaces, one step in "The Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris is to understand morphisms from affine schemes to projective spaces (Proposition III-40). The beginning is:

Let $T$ be a ring and $K$ a free summand of $T^{n+1}$ of rank $n$. Write $P$ for the invertible (i.e. locally free of rank 1) module $T^{n+1}/K$ which is generated by the $n+1$ images of the canonical generators $e_i$ of $T^{n+1}$.

Now, my problem is that I cannot show the following:

Let $I_j$ be the annihilator of $(P/T e_j)$ and $U_j$ the complement of $V(I_j)$, which is the set of all prime ideals $q$ of $T$ with $I_j\subset q$, in $\mathrm{Spec}(T)$. Then the $U_j$ form an open cover of $\mathrm{Spec}(T)$.

I think I miss something important about annihilators and the set $V(-)$ as I seem to not be able to show that the $U_j$ cover $\mathrm{Spec}(T)$ with the properties I know about locally free, invertible and/ or projective modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q\in\operatorname{Spec}(T)$.  Since $P$ is invertible, the localization $P_q$ is free of rank $1$ over $T_q$, and so it is generated by some single $e_j$ (namely, any $e_j$ that is not in $qP_q$).  That is, every $e_i$ becomes a multiple of this particular $e_j$ after localizing at $q$.  This means that for each $i$, there is some element $a_i\in T\setminus q$ such that $a_ie_i$ is a multiple of $e_j$.  Letting $a=\prod_i a_i$, we see that $ae_i$ is a multiple of $e_j$ for all $i$.  Since the $e_i$ generate $P$, this means $aP\subseteq Te_j$, so $a\in I_j$.  Since $a\in T\setminus q$, this means $q\in U_j$.